# Show the first two diagnoses for a patient in the first episode, but on the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to show the first two diagnoses for a patient in the first episode, but on the same row.  Sometimes patients do not have two diagnosis, so a null or blank would need to be returned. The diagnosis table fields are Patid, Epno (episode number), DiagNo, diagcode.  I want to show the result thus:  Patientno1  EpNo 1 Diagno1 DiagCode, Diagno 2 Diagcode.

Example:

```
Patient 123456 epno 1 DiagNo1 diagcode = W234 DiagNo2 Diagcode = e3456.  
Patient 890765 epno 1 diagNo1 diagcode = R345 (No second diagnosis)
```

I have tried selfjoins, but cannot get past the problem of no second diagnosis for patient 2.  Script below (The Spell table defines the date period for me).

```
SELECT distinct
 d1.PatID
,d1.diagno
,d1.DiagCode
,d1.DiagDesc as d1
,d2.diagno
,d2.DiagCode
,d2.DiagDesc AS d2 

  FROM spell s
left JOIN diagnosis d1 ON s.AdmNo = d1.AdmNo
right JOIN diagnosis d2 ON d1.AdmNo = d2.AdmNo AND d2.EpNo = d1.epno

  WHERE s.AdmDate>= '25-may-2018'
  AND d1.EpNo = 1 AND d1.DiagNo = 1 AND d2.EpNo = 1 

 GROUP BY
 d1.PatID
,d1.diagno
,d1.DiagCode
,d1.DiagDesc
,d2.diagno
,d2.DiagCode
,d2.DiagDesc
```

I am using SQLServer management Studio 2007.  I have googled this many times!  Any assistance, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Change your right join to a left join. Also move the predicates to the joins. When you have them in the where clause your outer joins have logically become inner joins. If that doesn't fix the issue then you need to provide us with some details. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1):

You would seem to want:

```
SELECT d1.PatID, d1.diagno, d1.DiagCode, d1.DiagDesc as d1,
       d2.diagno, d2.DiagCode, d2.DiagDesc AS d2 
FROM spell s LEFT JOIN
     diagnosis d1
     ON s.AdmNo = d1.AdmNo AND d1.EpNo = 1 and d1.diagno = 1 LEFT JOIN
     diagnosis d2
     ON s.AdmNo = d2.AdmNo AND d2.EpNo = d1.epno AND d2.diagno = 2 and d2.EpNo = 1 
WHERE s.AdmDate >= '2018-05-25';
```

You seem to be storing the multiple diagnoses in `diagnosis`, using `diagno` to distinguish them.

Notes:

- `RIGHT JOIN` is almost never useful.  Just use `LEFT JOIN`.
- From what you describe, neither `SELECT DISTINCT` nor `GROUP BY` is necessary.
- I don't think all your necessary join conditions are in your query.
- Your `where` clause undoes outer joins.
- Use standard date formats, such as YYYY-MM-DD.